# How should I cite a specific section of the LabVIEW online documentation?

Tags: citations, citation-style

How can I cite a specific page of the LabVIEW online documentation?

I need to cite these two pages: [from the tutorial](http://www.ni.com/tutorial/7595/en/) and [types of graphs and charts](http://zone.ni.com/reference/en-XX/help/371361J-01/lvconcepts/types_of_graphs_and_charts/).

Would I be better off citing the [online help documentation](http://zone.ni.com/reference/en-XX/help/371361P-01/)?

Comment: Not an answer, but I would suggest that there's nothing on those two pages that really warrants citation unless you're doing something that is really novel and unusual for your field. Most fields of engineering and science can safely assume that National Instruments plotting and computing software is a standard software package (like MATLAB or Mathematica) that might deserve mention but not citation.

Comment: Also consider that there are dozens and dozens of softwares that allow you to do plotting and that allow you to build and run state machines, so if this work is really so novel in your field that you feel like citation is deserved then you might want to spend a day looking up the different tools you might mention as well.

Comment: You can cite them as a webpage. This answer gives some info on that for a specific citation style: https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/67209/acs-style-image-citation/104049#104049

Answer (score 1):

It's generally best to provide the location of the cited material in such a way that, should a reader need to find it, they can do so without searching extensively. The pages you are citing are in two different locations (the first is a tutorial on the site and the second is essentially a section from the 2012 version of a manual) on the LabVIEW site so it likely makes the most sense to cite them separately from each other. There's always the potential issue of resources changing location and links breaking, so include other identifying details where possible, like page names and edition dates.